# vhdl ERRROR: Attribute "range" requires a constrained array prefix

Tags: vhdl

Two questions:

1. how to get rid of the warning: "Shared variables must be of a protected type." while keeping it as a "shared variable"?
2. How to fix Attribute "range" requires a constrained array prefix?

First of all, what is a constrained array prefix?

```sh
$ vcom.exe -2002 -l test3.vhd

** Warning: test3.vhd(14): (vcom-1236) Shared variables 
must be of a protected type.

** Error: test3.vhd(20): (vcom-14402) Attribute "range" 
requires a constrained array prefix.
```

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test3 is
end entity;

architecture beh of test3 is
    constant dw    :integer := 8;
    constant depth :integer := 128;
    
    type mem_t is array (integer range<>) of std_logic_vector(dw-1 downto 0);
    
    shared variable ram_block :mem_t(0 to depth-1);    
begin

process 
     variable i:integer;
begin
     for i in mem_t'range loop
         report integer'image(i);
     end loop;
end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: `mem_t` is an unconstrained type and hence the attribute `'range` cannot be used. I suggest using `ram_block` as the prefix.

Comment: Lets be real clear.   After VHDL-2000, shared variables of an ordinary type (such as your array of std_logic_vector) are illegal.   So an appropriate message in this case would be `Suppressed ERROR: test3.vhd(14): (vcom-1236) Shared variables 
must be of a protected type.`   It is deceptive by the tool vendor to issue it as a warning.

Comment: The fact that it is illegal is something that could be addressed in a future revision of the standard, but there would have to be someone willing to do the work to do the modifications - they would be numerous and tedious, but probably not too hard to do.   In the past, I have invited parties who have used this illegally, but they have decided not to even show up.

Comment: If you would like to see an appropriate way to do this, please see my blog post at:  https://osvvm.org/archives/1758

Answer (score 1):

A protected type in VHDL, is similar to a class in OO programming, where it can have member methods and it can retain state. Since 2002, it is required that shared variables must be of a protected type. By default, most tools only throw a warning to maintain backwards compatibility unless you turn on strict rule checking

So you have two options to remove the warning

1. revert to VHDL 1993 standard.
2. Create a protected type.

Your example shows no need for a shared variable. It could be made into a normal (non shared) variable inside the process.

Comment: *It could be made into a normal variable* the previous answer does with it's silently added a wait statement to the process in his design that does nothing but illustrate lack of attention to detail or research effort. Poor quality questions will continue as long as you answer. In 1999 P1076a produced IEEE Std 1076a-2000 introducing protected types and requiring shared variables to be of protected types which are not synthesis eligible, providing exclusive access to variables through methods. This was incorporated into IEEE Std 1076-2000 which was not well received.

Answer (score 0):

Question 2, I found... But Question 1, I'm still not sure about..

```vhdl
architecture beh of test3 is
    constant dw    :integer := 8;
    constant depth :integer := 128;
    
    type mem_t is array (integer range<>) of std_logic_vector(dw-1 downto 0);
    
    shared variable ram_block :mem_t(0 to depth-1);    
begin

process 
     variable i:integer;
begin
    report "left:"  & integer'image( ram_block'left);
    report "right:" & integer'image( ram_block'right);   
    
    for i in ram_block'range loop
        report integer'image(i);
    end loop;
    
    wait;
end process;


end architecture;
```